# The package at "node_modules/express/lib/express.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "events"

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, error-handling

I am getting this error "Failed building JavaScript bundle.
The package at "node_modules/express/lib/express.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "events". It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library. Read more at [https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries"](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries%22)

I have tried to install several dependencies with events included, but none of them works, please help

Comment: Your node modules might not be installed properly.

Comment: got answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had imported the package into the current file I was working in when I tried using URI for react native image picker

```
import { urlencoded } from "express";
```

When I removed it, it worked perfectly. Check your imports if you have any imports from express, remove it